# JavaScript issue with bouncing on windows' edges

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add on my website a script making a picture bouncing on the edges of the web browser, like the old DVD logo. At first it works, but when you reload the page, the limits are broken and the picture goes out of the frame.

Can't explain what's wrong, could anyone help me with this? Thanks :)

````
```JavaScript 
(function ($, window, undefined) {
$.fn.headgaelify = function (options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        horizontal: true,
        vertical: true,
        speed: 100, // In pixels per second
        container: $(this).parent(),
        bumpEdge: function () {}
    }, options);

    return this.each(function () {
        var containerWidth, containerHeight, elWidth, elHeight, move, getSizes,
            $el = $(this);

        getSizes = function () {
            containerWidth = settings.container.outerWidth();
            containerHeight = settings.container.outerHeight();
            elWidth = $el.outerWidth();
            elHeight = $el.outerHeight();
        };

        move = {
            right: function () {
                $el.animate({left: (containerWidth - elWidth)}, {duration: ((containerWidth/settings.speed) * 1000), queue: false, easing: "linear", complete: function () {
                    settings.bumpEdge();
                    move.left();
                }});
            },
            left: function () {
                $el.animate({left: 0}, {duration: ((containerWidth/settings.speed) * 1000), queue: false, easing: "linear", complete: function () {
                    settings.bumpEdge();
                    move.right();
                }});
            },
            down: function () {
                $el.animate({top: (containerHeight - elHeight)}, {duration: ((containerHeight/settings.speed) * 1000), queue: false, easing: "linear", complete: function () {
                    settings.bumpEdge();
                    move.up();
                }});
            },
            up: function () {
                $el.animate({top: 0}, {duration: ((containerHeight/settings.speed) * 1000), queue: false, easing: "linear", complete: function () {
                    settings.bumpEdge();
                    move.down();
                }});
            }
        };

        getSizes();

        if (settings.horizontal) {
            move.right();
        }
        if (settings.vertical) {
            move.down();
        }

  // Make that shit responsive!
  $(window).resize( function() {
    getSizes();
  });
    });
};
})(jQuery, window);

$(document).ready( function() {

$('.headgael').headgaelify({
    speed: 300,
    bumpEdge: function () {
        var newColor = "hsl(" + Math.floor(Math.random()*360) + ", 100%, 100%)";
        $('.headgael .logo').css('fill', newColor);
    }
});
});
````

Comment: Could you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to work with?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't manage how to do it... :/